# Should I include tag information in the title too?

Tags: discussion, questions

If you are going to ask a question specific to Debian, you have to give it a [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) tag. Fair enough. But I see many also mention the word Debian in the title as well:

```
How to remove dpkg in Debian?
# vs.
How to remove dpkg?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Stack Exchange search engine is a little limited, it really helps to have good information in the tags. But tags should be labels describing the content, not sources of additional information. Additionally, the titles are what you see if you're skimming the list of questions. It's important for them to be succinct statements of the key part of the question.

So, if a particular distribution is important to the question, yes, please put it in both places.

Comment: I'd also like to note that tags don't show in rss

Comment: @xeno - That's a good point.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Why do you want them to show there? Isn't it that you choose which tags you want, so no need to choose which RSS posts to see in you reader?

Comment: @tshepang I never said I did... I'm saying when people put that information in something besides tags I get it in rss. and I subscribe to the main new question feed, so my rss isn't filtered.

Comment: Typically people subscribe on a "per tag" basis. My RSS feeds show only tags that I've picked out as being relevant, so anything relevant to the question should definitively be in tags to get an audience. The tags even show up in the email digest if you subscribe to

Answer (score 7):

See

[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles)

> To be clear, I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles *organically and conversationally*.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth noting that your example question is not entirely specific to Debian, the same answers might apply to any dpkg based distro.

Keep alternate scenarios in mind when entering tags and titles. Sometimes being too specific might hurt your cause more than help it.

Comment: Imagine I'm someone who doesn't know that dpkg removal works the same in Debian and derivatives.